# Why are Kp Index values updating at times greater that the intervals in which they belong?

Tags: auroras

I've been observing the current Kp Index values from this [site](http://www.gfz-potsdam.de/en/section/earths-magnetic-field/data-products-services/kp-index/definitive/)

> At 12:18 AM UTC

The latest measurement is 1- (the next row for 160314 hasn't been filled out yet for the next series of measurements)

> 160313  1- 2- 1- 1-  0o 0o 0o 1-    4+      2 0.0

If the intervals go in order from 0000 - 0300, 0300 - 0600 to 2100 - 2400 then 
that value is the last which makes it fall into the interval 2100 - 0000 UTC. So why is there a value present in the last interval, shouldn't it belong in the next row - to the first interval of 160314 (i.e. 0000 - 0300)?

Or is there some sort of delay or shift I need to take into account?